# Changing images in loop doesn't work

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I use a for loop to show all elements via jQuery in this one function:

```
<script> 
$(function() {
    var number_menus = 9;
    for (i = 1; i <= number_menus; i++) {
        var p1 = +i;
        $(".wm_" + i).show()
            .css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");

        $(".wm_" + i).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css(
                "background-image", 
                "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + "_down.png)"
            );
            alert("this_down.png");
        });

        $(".wm_" + i).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css(
                "background-image", 
                "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)"
            );
        });
    }
});​
</script>
```

By other side i have this code for show all elements or images loading and create mouseover effect :

```
<div id="web_footer_publi">
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_1"></div> 
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_2"></div> 
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_3"></div> 
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_4"></div>
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_5"></div> 
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_6"></div> 
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_7"></div> 
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_8"></div>
  <div id="web_footer_marks" class="wm_9"></div>
</div>
```

When create the function think in show in loop all posibilities for all classes but when i go over images this show me other images of loop and works bad , i want , please , tell me what´s bad in this code for works with it

Thank´s !!

Comment: Hi Gerardo, you're going to want to switch your `id` and `class` attributes - the `id` attribute is designed to be unique, whereas the `class` attribute is not

Comment: Sorry if don´t understand something in this case you can tell me , ... don´t understand me and i go and edit , but sure if you go forum and speak spanish , italian and portugues sure i like see you writte ..... I speak 3 languages and english also and no use too and sure mistakes in many things ..... no only exist English .....

Comment: You don't need javascript for changing images like this. This should be done with CSS.

Comment: Ahh ok i must use id unmm i don´t think about this , i go try , thanks for your advise !

Comment: Yes i know but i want change images and create effects in this changes , i put easy example , before i have modifications with animate function for create transitions

Comment: You should swap your ids and your classes. Ids must be unique, but classes need not be. `class="web_footer_marks" id="wm_9"`, would be more appropriate. Then you use `$('#wm_9')` to reference by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is caused because of context. Create a closure inside the loop so the code executes straight away. There should be other ways to solve this too.

```
 <script> 
    $(function() {
        var number_menus = 9;
        for (i = 1; i <= number_menus; i++) {

    (function(i){

            var p1 = +i;
            $(".wm_" + i).show().css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + "_down.png)");
                alert("this_down.png");
            }).mouseout(function() {
                $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");
            });

    })(i);

        }
    });​
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm on a mobile device and can't get the formatting right

Comment: Put var into loop ? my function have this as you put here and no work me , i don´t understad if the loop generate all possibilities of classes , why no work .....

Answer (score 3):

instead of doing mouseover and mouseout use a bit of CSS usign `:hover` selector

```
<style>
.wm_1 {
  background-image: url(imagenes/footer/m/1.png);
}
.wm_1:hover {
  background-image: url(imagenes/footer/m/1_down.png);
}
</style>
```

no JS is needed

repeat this CSS for the rest nodes- 2,3,4...9

Comment: thanks @ahren, somethimes i'm quick more than i can handle :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach and see if it works

```
$(function() {
    var number_menus = 9;
    (function() { for (i = 1; i <= number_menus; i++) {
        var p1 = +i;
        $(".wm_" + i).show().css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");
        $(".wm_" + i).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + "_down.png)");
            alert("this_down.png");
        });
        $(".wm_" + i).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)");
        });
    } })(i);
});​
```

Comment: I mistypes a $ sing for the second function .. Remove that and try again

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would have a common class on all the elements that you can use to target all of them collectively; for example, in your case, it might be `class='wm'`. The class attribute does not have to be unique (whereas `id` does), so that is a reasonable class to have in common. Even if they are just similar, however, you don't need a for-loop -- just use the [attribute-starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) which can be used to target them all at once. For indexing, the property setters all have a method signature which accepts a function that can provide the index as a parameter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $specialDivs = $("div[class^='wm'");

    $specialDivs
        .show()
        .css("background-image", function (i) {
            return "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)";
        });
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", function (i) {
                return "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + "_down.png)";
            });
            alert("this_down.png");
        });
        .mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", function (i) {
                return "url(imagenes/footer/m/" + i + ".png)";
            });
        });
});
```

**However**, all of this is only useful if you <del>actually have something specific to do</del> *(see correction)* with these nodes, as opposed to a simple css effect on hover; those should be done with simple css:

```
div[class^='wm']:hover {
    background-image: ...;
}
```

-As a correction to the above, I suppose the fact that you have different background images for each one is a good enough reason to use JS rather than adding `n` css rules to handle each of your special blocks...